# update accidentally not installed

Tags: apt, openssh, raspberry-pi4, dpkg, debian-based

During apt upgrade I got an output like the following, unfortunately I pressed enter by mistake. Which is why a package was kept in the previous version. I think it was openssh-server, but I am not sure. I am using Raspberry Pi OS in the current version on a Raspberry Pi 4.

```
Configuration file '/etc/foo/foo.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
     Version in package is the same as at last installation.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** foo.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

My question is how can I re-trigger the update, or check which package was affected and reinstall that? I already ran apt upgrade again, but it said that 0 new packages can be loaded or installed.